# Cannot write my data to a file? I cannot see the error

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parsing

I have been trying for last few hours to narrow down an issue and I cannot see it. I'm new to Python 3 and trying parse a text file for a project. 
The parsing simply cleans up some whitespace and replaces delimitters. 
I don't understand why it won't work.

More specifically 
I am getting this particular error:

```
"NameError: name 'out' is not defined"
```

Code:

```
save_path = 'C:/UsersDesktop/CSVproject'

with open('C:/Users/CSVproject/sourceData.dat', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        if ':DUBLIN' in line:
            line = line.replace(' ', '')
            line = line.replace(':', ';')
            print(line)
            found = True
            fullNameOfFile = os.path.join(save_path, 'newFormattedData'+".csv")
            out = open(fullNameOfFile, 'w')

        for line in f:
            out.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to open the file each time the word :DUBLIN occurs. you only need to open it once and you should open it at a place where the scope ensures that the handle is visible to the write method.

```
fullNameOfFile = os.path.join(save_path, 'newFormattedData'+".csv")     

out = open(fullNameOfFile, 'w') 

for line in f:
    if ':DUBLIN' in line:
        line = line.replace(' ', '')
        line = line.replace(':', ';')
        print(line)
        found = True

        out.write(line)
```

And you definitely don't want to have a nested loop for iterating through the input file.

Comment: Oh shoot! I sheet you want you mean... I implemented your suggestion. Thank you for that. It creates the file as I wanted but it doesn't enforce the parsing logic in the replace methods. Nor does it print to console as I have in the code. I'm probably doing something very silly that I cant see...

Comment: Well this would solve your immidiately problem so would you mind accepting the answer as correct and posting another question. In that quesetion please explain what you are trying to achieve. What your sample input is like and what you want saved to the output file.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for your contribution. I don't want to come across as a spammy user of the site. I'll try the code some more before posting again.

Comment: yes, that's the right approach actually +1 from me for the attitude